# populate an ExpandableList with ArrayList of hashmaps

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap, expandablelistview

Can anybody tell me how to populate an Expandable List with Array List of Hash maps.
Actually i have made a tree Data structure and i want to use my Data Structure to populate the Expandable List....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example you will find how to do it with two arrays:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html

So just modify the code a little bit to make it work with your HashTable... really simple stuff.

Comment: i tried hard but do not now where i have to modify my code to make it work. can you please explain a bit.